# testing backbone.js view anonymous events with jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

How can i access click event outside the template scope.

What i have : HTML :

```
<div class="right_btn"></div>
<div id="template_loader">
    <!-- HTML template goes here which contain form inputs-->
    <input type="text" class="forgot_password_email" value="test" name="forgot_password_email"/>
</div>
```

View :

```
  var ForgotPasswordView = Backbone.View.extend({
       template: "templates/forgot-password-view.html",
       initialize: function () {
           console.log('Forgot Password View Initialized');
       },
   
       events:{
          'click .right_btn':function(e){
           alert($(".forgot_password_email").val());
           e.preventDefault();
       }
      }, 
   
  });
```

Kindly any one help , How can i write testcase to  access or triggger above click event outside template